# Program Losts After Await line

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, async-await

I'm calling post ajax method and I want the result in sequence and I want program to wait for the response. Basically, I want callback to come in sequence.

But after await line in TreeReportSentimentLoad function, program doesn't go on next line. It just basically stops there.
I want to make my code synchronous. I have multiple calls one after another, and i want their responses to be in same order.

Also, If i just do `async:false` in ajax call, page freezes, so this is why I'm trying this way but not working.

```
     return new Promise(resolve => {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: url,
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             async: true,

         })
     })
 }



async function TreeReportSentimentLoad() {

     url = "some url"       


     var promised = await ajaxCallForSentiment(url);
     console.log('after promise')
     promised.then(function (data) {
         console.log(data);
     })


 }

TreeReportSentimentLoad()
```

Comment: Are you call `resolve()` inside the ajax response callback ?

Comment: You never call `resolve` ...